# Extrapolation on ChartJS

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, linechart, extrapolation

i would like to extrapolate line chart (which have missing data at the beginning or at the end of the data series) using frontend JS libraries (like ChartJS)

It’s easy to do for inner data points (like "SpanGaps" properties). But outer data points… I cannot find a way.

It could be a constant value or a mathematical extrapolation, both are ok with me. But the data points must not be actually added to the data series because it would confuse users.

The red line needs that (it looks horrible otherwise)

[image]

Any ideas ?

Comment: Try asking on Software Recommendations